# Adding to view angles in unity?

Tags: unity, c#

I'm trying to make a save/load position script in unity. I have coded the position portion but how would I go about doing this for a camera?

```
//Grabbing mouse input
    rotX -= Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse Y") * xMouseSensitivity * 0.02f;
    rotY += Input.GetAxisRaw("Mouse X") * yMouseSensitivity * 0.02f;

//Applying after clamp
    this.transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotY, 0); // Rotates the collider
    playerView.rotation     = Quaternion.Euler(rotX, rotY, 0); // Rotates the camera
```

So when I press my save button it saves the view angles, but how would I write to camera/collider?

Input.GetAxisRaw gets called every frame so when I add saved values to x & y then get overwritten the next frame, since it's just going off the mouse values.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks :)

Comment: It's not clear to me what problem you need help solving. Consider showing your current save/load code to remove any ambiguity about how you've implemented this so far.